# DISTINCT values in LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I get a list of values with `LISTAGG`.
Is it possible to get the values only once in the list of `LISTAGG`?

Sample Query:

```
SELECT
table1.id AS ID,
LISTAGG(table2.object_id,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY table2.object_id) AS my_list 
FROM 
table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.tbl1_id
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Sample Output:

```
ID     MY_LIST
25     123;456;123;857
```

Needed Output:

```
ID     MY_LIST
25     123;456;857
```

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean by using

    LISTAGG(DISTINCT table2.object_id,';') ?

Comment: Do not duplicate: [CONCAT for each LISTAGG value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75735125/concat-for-each-listagg-value)

Comment: @MaciejLos this is not a duplicate. This are different questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
--  Since version 19c you could use:
Select  LISTAGG(DISTINCT column_name, ';') WITHIN GROUP (Order By column_name)
From    table_name

--  Before 19c
Select  LISTAGG(column_name, ';') WITHIN GROUP (Order By column_name)
From    (   Select  DISTINCT column_name 
            From    table_name
        )
```