# CONCAT for each LISTAGG value

Tags: sql, oracle

is it possible to `CONCAT` another value for each `LISTAGG` value?

Sample query:

```
SELECT
table1.id AS ID,
LISTAGG(table2.object_id,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY table2.object_id) AS my_list 
FROM 
table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.tbl1_id
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Sample output:

```
ID     MY_LIST
25     123;456;123;857
```

Needed output:

```
ID     MY_LIST
25     123 = 4;456 = 6;857 = 2
```

Comment: where's 2,6,2 come from?  You need to show all table DDL and sample table data for each

Comment: Of course, just place the concatenation as the first argument to LISTAGG.... LISTAGG(col1||' = '||col2,';')....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will work, maybe it won't, depending on whether the length of the resulting column would be less than 4000 chars...
I think the below would produce what you need.

```
SELECT
       table1.id AS ID,
       LISTAGG(table2.object_id||'='||table2.id,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY table2.object_id) AS my_list 
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.tbl1_id
GROUP BY table1.id
```